# Sublime Text 3 - How to change UI text font on a 3rd party theme?

Tags: fonts, themes, sublimetext3

I'm new in web design and developing and I'll have an thesis about my subject, so I want to customize my Sublime in my own way so I'll be happy on using it when I'm about to code (I am very design sensitive person) so I tried to theme as beautiful as I could, so I used the [Material theme by equinusocio](https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme) so I installed in by Package Control and enabled, tweaked it, downloaded the Roboto and Roboto Mono font (the official fonts for Material design) and set it on the. I was able to chane the font of the code canvas but I want to change the Ui font also, so I researched online about this and found out about the `"class": "sidebar_label"` but the problem is I'm not able to use it properly because I don't know yet on the JSOn and it's hiercacy. I'm not able to save it because it shows an error. Although it says where it exactly was, I don't know how to correct it. And then after the Sublime restarts, it goes back to the ugly default skin

Here's the code, please help me correct it:

```
{
     "class": "sidebar_label"
     , "color": [0, 0, 0]
     , "font.face": "Roboto" // ADDED THIS LINE     
},
{
      "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
      "bold_folder_labels": true,
      "class": "sidebar_label",
      "color_scheme": "Packages/Material Theme/schemes/OLD/Material-Theme-          Darker.tmTheme",
      "font_face": "Roboto Mono",
      "font_size": 12,
      "indent_guide_options":
             [
                   "draw_normal",
                   "draw_active"
             ],
      "line_padding_bottom": 3,
      "line_padding_top": 3,
      "material_theme_accent_indigo": true,
      "material_theme_compact_sidebar": true,
      "material_theme_small_statusbar": true,
      "material_theme_small_tab": true,
      "material_theme_tabs_autowidth": true,
      "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
      "theme": "Material-Theme-Darker.sublime-theme"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a change in the theme not in the settings. Hence you must change the theme. The easiest way to do this is to install the [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) and run the command `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`. Afterwards navigate to file `Material-Theme.sublime-theme` and open it. If you have installed the theme via Package Control, then it should be inside a zip file. However if you save the file, this should be created in the right folder and the saved theme hides the original one.

Now just search for `sidebar_label` and apply your changes. If you want to have the original theme just remove or rename the file.